# Recoger datos multiples de mysql a checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, checkbox

Tengo un problema para que se me marquen los checkboxes de un formulario.

El caso es que tengo un datatable con un listado, en el que entre otras tengo una columna "fallos".
Este es una cadena de texto introducida al marcar multiples checkboxes mediante implode.

Al editar alguna fila de la datatable quiero recoger los datos de MySQL y que se marquen por defecto.
He conseguido que se marque los checkboxes correspondientes, pero siempre me coge la primera fila de mi base de datos y no sé como indicarle que coja la correspondiente a la fila marcada.
Tengo creado una Key autoincrementable llamada "id_registro" con la que supongo que debo relacionarla, pero no se como.

He conseguido que me coja algún otro valor, pero no automáticamente.

Utilizo el código siguiente:

```
<?php

$checked_arr = array();
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'check_in');

$idregistro2 = '8';
$fetchFallos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM t_registro WHERE id_registro = $idregistro2" );
if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchFallos) > 0){
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchFallos);
$checked_arr = explode(",",$result['fallos']);
}

// Create checkboxes
$fallos_arr = array("Cristales","Suelo","Cama");
foreach($fallos_arr as $fallos){
$checked = "";
if(in_array($fallos,$checked_arr)){
    $checked = "checked";
    }
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="calificaciones[]" value="'.$fallos.'" '.$checked.' > '.$fallos.' <br/>';
}
?>
```

Si cambio el "8" de $idregistro2 por otro número me coge la fila correspondiente a dicho id_registro que es la primera columna tipo key que tengo.

¿Pero cómo lo hago automáticamente? ¿Cómo puedo recuperar el id_registro activo de MySQL?

Un saludo.

---

A ver si dando alguna pista más alguien puede ayudarme.

Si en el formulario ingreso el siguiente código me devuelve la fila en la que se encuentra:

```
<input type="text" id="idregistro" name="idregistro"><br>
```

Dentro del input, pero no se como poder cogerlo para hacerlo constante y poder incluir el valor en el WHERE.

Una ayuda por favor.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Probaste enviado el input idregistro por post y luego recibirlo en php tipo $idregistro2 = $_POST['idregistro']; ?